# Advice on testing MediatR controllers and handlers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I have a very subjective question, and I would like some opinions. I know there is no right answer, and sorry if this is against the rules, but I'm posting it because it may help others.

In my project, 99% of the controllers follow the following model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("filter")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<MyDTO>> Filter([FromBody] MyCommand data)
    {
        var result = await Mediator.Send(data);

        return HttpResponse(result);
    }
```

I receive an object that is a command class and this object is then sent to Mediator. The response is sent to the `HttpResponse` method in my `BaseController`, and this method is responsible for interpreting the Mediator answer and return 200, 400, 500, etc and map the response to a DTO when needed.

The `BaseController` has its own tests, **so is there any reason/advantage of testing these controllers?** I see that if I do that, I'm just testing the MediatR library and I can not see the point of it.

Now let's talk about the MediatR handlers. Some of my handlers have a little bit of logic, so I really need to test them.  But some other handlers work only as a shortcut to a given service, like this:

`MediatR handler`

```
    public class Handler : BaseQueryHandler<Command>
    {
        private readonly IAnalyticModuleStore _context;

        public Handler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IAnalyticModuleStore context)
            : base(httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override async Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Command request)
        {
            return await _context.FilterAsync(request.DateFrom, request.DateTo, request.Versions, request.Areas, request.Domains, request.Actions,
                request.Users, request.Agents, request.Responses, null, request.Duration, request.EntityId);
        }
    }
```

Don't worry about the `BaseQueryHandler`, it is properly tested.

This is how I would write a test for this handler: mock the `IAnalyticModuleStore` service and the `FilterAsync` method, then create a command and send it to the handler to assert the response values.

But assuming that the `IAnalyticModuleStore.FilterAsync` method is properly tested, in the end, what I'm testing is a fake object. **Is there any reason/advantage of testing these handlers?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to assume that MediatR and the class that implements IAnalyticModuleStore are properly tested.

Therefore it is reasonable to skip testing controllers or handlers of the kind you have mentioned.

If you wish to strictly write unit tests you can, for example, verify that a command passed to the Filter method is passed "as is" to MediatR's Send method, and that the HttpResponse returned by Filter contains the same object returned by the Send method (Send should of course be mocked).

Personally, I would have skipped such tests.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to wrap controller with single happy path test without mocking.

You can run self-hosted integration tests for your application.
Such tests provide very valuable feedback - that your application and it's internals are configured correctly.
I would even suggest to use actual database(not "in-memory" version) for these tests.

Such tests will give you or your colleagues more freedom for future changes.

Notice that you heavily relying on third-party framework as MediatR, which in your case is nothing then simple dictionary which can be automatically generated with modern source generator in C#.
With such tests you can freely decide what techniques to use.

Later you possibly decide to get rid of handlers and move their code back to controllers, because looks like your handlers contain controllers code.  With integration tests you can do it and after few minutes of running tests you will know did you break something or not.

Notice that I am not talking about covering all possible cases with such tests, but only single happy path and maybe one or two other very critical cases.